# Azure web app, custom status code description does not work

Tags: asp.net, azure, powershell, http, iis

I deploy an ASP.NET  to Azure web app. 
This web app have endpoint /usageinfo with custom status code description 
Below is the result in localhost:
[image: Localhost result]

However, the web app show different result:
[image: Web app result]

Code

```
  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(usageInfo >= 95 ? 503 : 200,
                $"Account {BomEnvironment.EmbedUsername}. UsageInfo={usageInfo}");
```

Why are they different?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you put that in the status code DESCRIPTION? Shouldn't that information go into the body of the response? The HTTP protocol doesn't have an entry for `200 Account something did something`, just [`200 OK`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.3.1). The fact that it works on localhost is a rather strange artefact of that `HttpStatusCodeResult` method.

Comment: Thank you for support. I want to know root cause clearly before mark your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test in my site with the following code and it work both on local and on azure.

```
public HttpStatusCodeResult HelloWorld()
{
    var aa = "joey";
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, $"Account {aa}.");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for testing. I will check with another Azure web applcation

Comment: As I tested, if we use other status that is different with 200, custom status descrption working well in web application. However, I have no idea why 200 status code is working in localhost